# Bug in LINQ to SQL with empty strings on database

Tags: c#, .net, t-sql, linq-to-sql, string-length

I have been using LINQ to SQL for years now, but this is the first time I have seen this behavior.

I have a DB table with a few columns (`varchar(15)`) that may contain empty strings (`''`). I verify this by running `LEN(Column)` and checking the result be `0`.

Now when I call this from LINQ2SQL, it returns the object field with a string containing a single space (`string.Length == 1`).

There are a few workarounds I could apply, like making them `NULL` on the DB or trimming the string, but I would like to know if anyone has come across this before or if the bug is known (reported on MS Connect). If not, I'll report it.

Thanks.

Comment: Is it this happening to differentiate between NULL value and empty string ? For ex: In a file how would you store a NULL string (file len = 0) and a empty string (also file len = 0). In OO world NULL string and empty string are 2 different things whereas in data world they seems to be same

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is with the `LEN` function:

```
SELECT LEN(' ')
```

Returns 0 in SQL Server; it is a total PITA.

But

```
SELECT DATALENGTH(' ')
```

Returns 1

Comment: Sweet thanks! One of our DB guys also learnt something new :)

Comment: Just to add, `LEN` with ignore trailing whitespace.

Comment: It's been annoying me for months now!

Comment: Edit: `LEN` will ignore trailing whitespace

Comment: A kind of corollary to this is that `SELECT LEN(LTRIM(CHAR(9)))` returns 1; CHAR(9) is the TAB character; this makes trimming white space a huge PITA too!